# Is it bad practice to store keys in .properties file

Tags: android, security

So i've just integrated with UrbanAirship for Android.

Their sample code uses a `.properties` file to store API keys and secrets. I found this quite alarming as these files are easily accessible after expanding an APK.

I'm not looking to start a debate about storing sensitive data in your app. I just want to know if it is unacceptable to store keys like this.

If so then which is a more secure but straight forward approach? I am currently storing my own API keys as static variables in a globals file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since APK contents are not encrypted, the string is just as easily extracted from a .properties file than from a compiled class. You can make it a little harder to extract by storing it encrypted inside your Globals class, but don’t expect anything you ship to users to remain a secret.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a secure way to load the keys into memory, request them from a server of your own at runtime over a secure channel. Even if you store the keys in shared preferences / databases which are only accessible from your program, a rooted device will work around that since it has access to all files. Class / Dex files can be reverse engineered at anytime.

Also take a look at tools like [dexguard](http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard). It provides more obfuscation, security features than proguard.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to Urban Airship; The key and secret you place in the .properties file are essentially for the analytics call and not actual "pushing". You are given a master secret as well for API call though. This is the app secret value that you need to protect. This is why Urban Airship discourages pushing from a device which requires the app key and master secret. If you are only storing Urban Airship's app key and secret, there is no security issue.